# Youtube Video Uploading Api With Oauth by using api key

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I search YouTube video uploading API all the example I see is based on Oauth and its use client id and secrete key.  However I have seen using api key, but code not found any were i want it will use in core php .. by curl...

So if anyone has code and suggestion please help me..

thanks.

Comment: I don't think "you" have the ability to upload using API key because the YouTube API only supports Oauth2 for uploading.    You are not going to find any code for it because its not possible use Oauth2.

Comment: i have seen this has been also be done by api key... without auth

Comment: API key is used for accessing public data only.  You may have seen something but it was not uploading videos using the a Public API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)  it requires authentication and authorization using the following scopes.

> Authorization
>   
>   This request requires authorization with at least one of the following
>   scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)).
>
> Scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

**API keys** are used for accessing public data only.

Comment: thanks i am using it but its display error Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Application: youtube

Comment: That is a different question, you should create a new question for that.  Or google it there are probably 100 answers for that error.   redirect_uri must be set correctly in the Google Developers console.   It must match the URI you are sending the rest from.

Comment: Can you help me for uploading video on my own channel right now i have done video uploading but its upload video on user channel

Comment: The videos will upload to the channel owned by the person who authenticates your application.